# Excel - find last value in column within current date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created the following table for tracking version releases for a web and app project, listing current and future release dates and versions for the platform.

I want the top row to automatically select the value furthers down it's respective column, but only when the date in column A is equal to or less than todays date.

[image: sample table]

The formula I had been using for row 2 previously looked like this:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(1-ISBLANK(B:B)),B:B)
```

This formula works well to find the last value in the column, but I need to somehow add in logic that ensures it shows the latest version build released to date.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a dynamic named range (as a `Name` via *Formulas* ribbon | *Define Name*). Use a formula like:

```
=OFFSET($A$3,1,0,COUNTIF($A$3:$A$1000,"<="&TODAY()))
```

You can check that it's correct by selecting it from the Name Manager and you'll see the selected cells representing this range of dates <= today's date:

[image]

Then, add another `Name` for browser (and repeat for iOS, etc.) like:

```
=OFFSET(released_dates,0,1)
```

[image]

Then, instead of using the entirety of column B in your `Lookup` formula, you can refer to the named range `browser_releases`!

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(1-ISBLANK(browser_releases)),browser_releases)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!
I did have one strange bug whereby it wasn't displaying the value for the last date entered within the date range if todays date didn't exist in the date column. reasonably odd so any advice you can give on that would be appreciated.

In the interim, I placed a hidden row down the bottom with an =TODAY() formula in the cell. Not an ideal solution but has at least fixed that weird issue up for now.